# Auto-Unlock on a manually Continuity-enabled Mac?

Tags: mac, apple-watch, continuity

I have a brand new Apple Watch Series 1, an iPhone 6 running iOS 10.0.1 public beta, and an early 2011 MacBook Pro with an upgraded AirPort card and [Continuity Activation Tool](https://github.com/dokterdok/Continuity-Activation-Tool/) running the latest Sierra public beta. Handoff and AirDrop and other Continuity features have been working fine lately between my phone and my laptop, but how do I get Auto Unlock to work? I tried following [these](http://www.cultofmac.com/441405/how-to-use-apple-watch-to-unlock-your-mac-in-macos-sierra/) steps for enabling Auto Unlock in general, but System Preferences isn't showing me an "Allow your Apple Watch to unlock your Mac" checkbox. How can I make that box appear? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**What hardware is required for Auto Unlock?**

According to Apple’s macOS Sierra beta 2 release notes, Auto Lock requires a 2013 or later Mac. That means that even 2012 Macs with Bluetooth 4.0 don’t officially support Auto Unlock.

**What software is required for Auto Unlock?**

To use Auto Unlock, you’ll need to be running macOS Sierra Developer Preview Seed 2. You’ll also need to have the watchOS 3 beta installed on your Apple Watch. Apple indicates that the latest version of watchOS 3 (beta 2) needs to be installed, but I was able to get Auto Unlock working with watchOS 3 beta 1.

**You’ll also need to have Two-Factor Authentication established for the iCloud account associated with your Mac and Apple Watch.**

**How do I set up Two-Factor Authentication?**

Two-Factor Authentication can be set up via the Apple ID website. Beware that a small number of users are complaining of being locked out of their accounts when enabling 2FA on the developer beta.

Keep in mind that Two-Factor Authentication differs from Two-Step Authentication. You must be using Two-Factor Authentication for Auto Unlock to work. If you need assistance, a [full guide for enabling Two-Factor Authentication](https://9to5mac.com/2016/03/22/how-to-enable-two-factor-authentication-on-ios-9-and-os-x-el-capitan/).

Once 2FA is enabled, Apple encourages users to do the following:

- On your Mac, open System Preferences →  iCloud, and click the Account
  Details button. Click the Security tab, and make sure Two-Factor
  Authentication is on. On your iPhone, open Settings →  iCloud and tap
  on your name to reveal account details. Tap on the Password and
  Security item, and make sure sure Two-Factor Authentication is on.
- On your iPhone, open Watch →  General →  Apple ID, and verify your
  Apple ID is showing.
- How do I enable Auto Unlock?

**Enabling Auto Unlock is handled on your Mac via System Preferences → Security & Privacy.**

***I’m not seeing the Auto Unlock setting in System Preferences***

After performing a clean install, it can take minutes for the Allow your Apple Watch to unlock your Mac checkbox to display in System Preferences → Security and Privacy → General on your Mac. This delay occurs while your devices are iCloud pairing. If you performed an upgrade instead of a clean install, you should not experience any delays.

If you’re still having problems getting Auto Unlock to work, try rebooting all three devices (Mac, Apple Watch, paired iPhone). Also, double-check to make sure you have Two-Factor Authentication enabled, not Two-Step Authentication.